# Displaying qwt plot on UI form

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qwt

I have my "MainWindonw" file and "Plot" file with a class to plot.

Currently I can display my Plot in two different ways:

1. I can create in my UI form a widget and promote the Plot class. (in this way I can put my Plot in any place that I want)
2. I can use the explicit declaration on code as:

   ```
   d_plot = new Plot( this );
   ....
   setCentralWidget( d_plot );
   ```

   However in this way I can't have control on my Plot, it just go to mainwindow

So my question is, how can I use something like the the code from item 2 to plot on my widget on UI form.

It's possible to do something like:

```
    setWidgetCreated (d_plot);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create dplot with the right widget as a parent. Supposing for example the container widget is a QGroupBox name gbox, you'll create it with this code:

```
dplot = new Plot(ui->gbox);
```

You'll likely need to apply some Layout. Have a look to the QT documentation for details. Some page you may find useful:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/layout.html

(By the way, I strongly prefer the first method, promoting the widget.)

Comment: When I promote the class the plot stay for example 208,190. However, when I use this code that you suggested my plot stay really small like 50,100. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: As I said, you should put a layout. The documentation I posted will guide you through.